# Bug in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012

I found one bug in microsoft visual studio 2012 v4.5, In which website should i post it. Pls give me any link for that. I searched more for that but i didn't found any solution for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official place to post all bugs for Microsoft related products here:

http://connect.microsoft.com/

To submit bugs for `Visual Studio`, you can use this page:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/

Or more directly:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/CreateFeedbackForm.aspx?FeedbackFormConfigurationID=5303&FeedbackType=1